# Как обновить или перезапустить весь код?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Я хочу перейти на другое окно после нажатия кнопки.
Желательно в том же окне но уже без старого содержимого

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Window1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.setStyleSheet("background:red;")



class Window2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.setStyleSheet("background:blue;")

        self.but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.but.setText("Click me")
        self.but.clicked.connect(self.run)

    def run(self):
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
            w = Window1()
            w.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
        #self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window2()
    w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Я знаю что могу просто

```
class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        win1 = Window1(self)
        win2 = Window2(self)
        win2.hide()
```

Но я не хочу загружать свой компьютер лишним кодом и процессами

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Window1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.setStyleSheet("background: red;")


class Window2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.setStyleSheet("background: blue;")

        self.but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.but.setText("Click me")
        self.but.clicked.connect(self.close)      # - run)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    print(f"app:      {app}, \ninstance: {QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()}")
    w = Window2()
    w.show()
    app.exit(app.exec())
    
    app2 = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    print(f"\napp2:     {app2}, \ninstance: {QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()}")
    w = Window1()
    w.show()
    app2.exit(app2.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> В таком случае второе окно появится вне зависимоти от того нажал я на кнопку или просто закрыл окно. Мне нужно переключатся между двумя объектами. а не устанавливать очередь на открытие окон

Sorry, я как обычно плохо понимаю, что вы хотите сделать.
Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class Window1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.setStyleSheet("background: red;")


class Window2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.setStyleSheet("background: blue;")

        self.but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.but.setText("Click me")
        self.but.clicked.connect(self._close)      # - run)
        
        self.flag_close = None
        
    def _close(self):
        self.flag_close = True
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    print(f"app:      {app}, \ninstance: {QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()}")
    w = Window2()
    w.show()
    app.exit(app.exec())
    
    if w.flag_close:
        app2 = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        print(f"\napp2:     {app2}, \ninstance: {QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()}")
        w = Window1()
        w.show()
        app2.exit(app2.exec())
```

---

**Update 2**

> Вы можете как эксперт проверить мой вариант?

я честно не понимаю, что вы хотите сделать
и не понимаю логику примера, который вы предложили в ответе для анализа.
Вот вам еще один вариант (последний), просто попробуйте
понажимать на кнопки. Может это то, что вам надо.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.count_pages = 0
        self.pages_grid_list = [] 
        self.h_layout = None
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        count = 0
        for count_pages in range(0, 2):
            widget = QWidget()  
            widget.setStyleSheet("background: blue;" if count_pages==0 else "background: red;")
            grid_layout = QGridLayout(widget)      
            for x in range(0, 4):
                for y in range(0, 4):
                    count = count + 1
                    button = QPushButton(str(count))
                    button.setFixedSize(50, 50)
                    button.setStyleSheet("background: #ccc;" )
                    button.clicked.connect(self.get_btn_clicked)
                    grid_layout.addWidget(button, x, y, Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.pages_grid_list.append(widget)

        next_page_button = QPushButton('next')
        next_page_button.clicked.connect(self.next_page_action)
        previous_page_button = QPushButton('previous')
        previous_page_button.clicked.connect(self.previous_page_action)

        self.h_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.h_layout.addWidget(previous_page_button, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.h_layout.addWidget(self.pages_grid_list[self.count_pages])          # +++
        self.h_layout.addWidget(next_page_button, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter)

    def get_btn_clicked(self):
        button = self.sender()
        print('вы кликнули: {}'.format(button.text()))  

    def next_page_action(self):
        self.count_pages = self.count_pages + 1
        if self.count_pages < len(self.pages_grid_list):
            self.new_page(self.count_pages)
        else:
            self.count_pages = len(self.pages_grid_list) - 1

    def previous_page_action(self):
        self.count_pages = self.count_pages - 1
        if self.count_pages >= 0:
            self.new_page(self.count_pages)
        else:
            self.count_pages = 0
            
    def new_page(self, count_pages):
        widget = self.h_layout.takeAt(1).widget()
        widget.hide()
        self.h_layout.insertWidget(1, self.pages_grid_list[count_pages])  
        self.pages_grid_list[count_pages].show()     


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В таком случае второе окно появится вне зависимоти от того нажал я на кнопку или просто закрыл окно. Мне нужно переключатся между двумя объектами.
а не устанавливать очередь на открытие окон.

Comment: @orlatym попробуйте мое обновление.

Comment: Вы можете как эксперт проверить мой вариант?

Comment: @orlatym я добавил еще один вариант, посмотрите.

Comment: Вы меня неправильно поняли. Я хочу попробовать создать динамический контент. Если я буду просто скрывать ненужный контент то он
все еще остаётся в системе засоряя память

Answer (score 0):

Я создал свой вариант правда я не знаю насколько мой вариант бьет по производительности если кто разбирается лучше может мне сказать

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Window1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.setFixedHeight(300)
        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.main = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.main)
        self.main.setStyleSheet("background: red;")

class Window2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedWidth(500)
        self.setFixedHeight(500)
        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.main = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.main)
        self.main.setStyleSheet("background: blue;")

        self.but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.but.setText("Click me")

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.w = Window2(self)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.w)
        
        self.w.but.clicked.connect(self.close)
        
        self.but2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.but2.setText("Click me2")
        self.but2.move(100,100)
        self.but2.clicked.connect(self.close)
        
    def close(self):
        print(self.w.but.text())
        #self.but2.setParent(None)
        self.w.deleteLater()
        self.w = None
        self.w = Window1(self)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.w)
        self.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.exit(app.exec())
```

Я понял как проверить код на производительность правда не уверен насколько.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Window1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.setFixedHeight(300)
        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.main = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.main)
        self.main.setStyleSheet("background: red;")

class Window2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedWidth(500)
        self.setFixedHeight(500)
        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.main = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.main)
        self.main.setStyleSheet("background: blue;")

        self.but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.but.setText("Click me")

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.w = Window2(self)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.w)
        
        self.w.but.clicked.connect(self.close)
        
        # проверка на производительность
        self.but2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.but2.setText("Click me 2")
        self.but2.move(0,100)
        self.but2.clicked.connect(self.add)
        
        self.but3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.but3.setText("Click me 3")
        self.but3.move(0,50)
        self.but3.clicked.connect(self.add2)
        
        self.num = 0

    def add2(self):
        print("Click me 3-{}".format(self.num))
        self.num += 1
        s = 0
        while s < 10000 :
            s += 1
            self.but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.but.setText("Click me"+str(s))
            self.w.lay.addWidget(self.but)
            self.but.hide()
        
        
    def add(self):
        print("Click me 2-{}".format(self.num))
        self.num += 1
        s = 0
        while s < 10000 :
            s += 1
            self.but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
            self.but.setText("Click me"+str(s))
            self.w.lay.addWidget(self.but)
            self.but.deleteLater()
            self.but.setParent(None)
            self.but = None
    
        
    def close(self):
        print(self.w.but.text())
        self.w.deleteLater()
        self.w.setParent(None)
        self.w = None
        self.w = Window1(self)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.w)
        self.update()
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.exit(app.exec())
```

Начальные параметры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нажать на Click me 2 десять раз

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нажать на Click me 3 десять раз

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]